# Postgresql: [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text || integer[]

Tags: postgresql

I getting error like below: [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text || integer[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. I cannot fix this problem and tried so many times.

My Code:

```
DECLARE

arr_operators       integer[1,2];

BEGIN
query1 := 'SELECT * FROM dist.' || _rec1.table_name || ' WHERE operator_id = ANY (''' || arr_operators || ''');';

FOR _rec IN EXECUTE query1 LOOP

END LOOP;
```

I think problem is happening when I am makin query string.But when I use this statement in query directly lik below is working well:

```
FOR _rec1 IN (SELECT * FROM dist.sirdarya WHERE id = any (arr_operators)) LOOP

         INSERT INTO dist.justt(column1,column2) VALUES (_rec1.id,_rec1.msisdn);

END LOOP;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cast it to text: `query1 := 'SELECT * FROM dist.' || _rec1.table_name || ' WHERE operator_id = ANY (''' || arr_operators::TEXT || ''');';`

Comment: but operator_id and arr_operators  are integer, does it work?

Comment: Yes it works fine, the cast is only for creating the query string, you'll end up with `... = ANY('{1,2,3}')` which should be implicitly cast to an integer array when the query is executed.

Comment: ok, thank you bro for your help. It is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest unnesting an array instead of concatenating string which could lead to SQL Injection:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE operator_id IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(arr_operators));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=020f48d96bb6bab79b157ac07c0456fe)**

---

This part is particulary dangerous:

```
query1 := 'SELECT * FROM dist.' || _rec1.table_name
```

What if table name is let's say: `;DROP DATABASE ...;--`?

It could be rewritten as:

```
query1 := FORMAT('SELECT * FROM dist.%I ...', _rec1.table_name);
```

Comment: but table_name should be changed

Comment: @AbdusoliErgashev `FORMAT(' %I')` is  doing it